# Is there a way to call a stored MySQL procedure include insert parameters with Dapper in C#?

Tags: c#, mysql, dapper

```
public void InsertUser(string firstname, string lastname, string email, string password, int age)
{
    using (IDbConnection connection = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(Helper.CnnVal("Database")))
    {
        List<user> users = new List<user>();
        users.Add(new user { Firstname = firstname, Lastname = lastname, Email = email, Password = password, Age = age });
        connection.Execute("InsertUserProcedure", @Firstname,@Lastname,@Email,@Password,@Age,users);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following is *general* guidance that applies to most ADO.NET providers; it does not take into account any MySQL peculiarities or nuances (because I'm not a MySQL user)

If the stored procedure parameters match exactly the properties on `user`, then you should be able to do this simply as;

```cs
connection.Execute(
    "InsertUserProcedure", users, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

If there are more properties on `user` than the stored procedure wants, then one approach is to invoke the stored procedure indirectly via `EXEC` / `CALL` (as a `CommandText`, which is the default):

```cs
connection.Execute(
    "EXEC InsertUserProcedure @Firstname,@Lastname,@Email,@Password,@Age", users);
```

(or the same with `CALL` instead of `EXEC`, on MySQL apparently - see comments)

Another approach is to use `Select` as a projection, allowing you to use the stored procedure directly, but limiting the properties that are passed in.:

```cs
connection.Execute("InsertUserProcedure", users.Select(u => new {
        u.Firstname, u.Lastname, u.Email, u.Password, u.Age
    }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

Comment: Hi Marcthe stored procedure parameters match exactly the properties on user

Comment: but I will get error of lastname column cant be null

Comment: @Mily did you specify `commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure` ?

Comment: if I use your sec script I get Syntax error and ask to check MariaDb server version

Comment: @Mily maybe try `:Firstname,:Lastname,:Email,...` etc? I'm not a MySQL person, but I know Dapper "pretty well"

Comment: yes I did 
connection.Execute("InsertUserProcedure", users, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure );

Comment: no doesn't work still, the third script also gives an error under Commandtype which saying select does not have a parameter named 'commandtype

Comment: I have the code for SQL server and works fine but MySQL syntax is a bit different
connection.Execute("dbo.users_insert @Firstname,@Lastname,@Email,@Password,@Age",users);

Comment: Marc's code works perfectly for me (using MySqlConnector or MySql.Data). The only change necessary is `connection.Execute("CALL InsertUserProcedure(@Firstname,@Lastname,@Email,@Password,@Age)", users);` for the non-`CommandType.StoredProcedure` approach, but using `CommandType.StoredProcedure` will work fine (even if there are more properties on `users` than the stored procedure accepts).

Comment: @Bradley that's useful, thanks; have clarified in an edit